# How to pass an image into a html textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm wondering how to pass an image from an image-gallery into a html-textarea. Should i use jquery/javascript and do you know some good tutorial on this function?

Comment: Can't you show a bit of your code ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not because i'm on my cellphone. But also because i dont have any code because i dont lnow where to start to code the function.

Answer (score 11):

After choosing an image via os built-in selector

```
<input type="file"../>
```

you can pass image data(base64 encoded string) to an image tag located within a editable div by using file reader api.

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>

#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

</style>
<body>

<input class="file" type='file' id="imgSel" />

<div id="textarea" contenteditable>

  <img contenteditable="false" style="width:45px" id="myimg" />
  I look like a textarea

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById('myimg').setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    document.getElementById('imgSel').onchange = function () { //set up a common class
        readURL(this);
    };


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

How to make and editable div look like a textarea element:

```css
#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 118px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>
  
  <img contenteditable="false" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Koala-ag1.jpg" width="120" height="100"/>
  
  I look like a textarea</div>
```

you can set *contenteditable="false"* on img element to make it not editable.

https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/

Comment: I will check this solution as soon as possible :)

Comment: now it really looks like a textarea:)

Comment: Im not shure if this is the sulution im searching for. If i writing a blogpost and want to include some image content to the post. What i want to do is to click on some button like "insert image" and then will i be able to choose an image to click on and than the image will be passed to the textarea.

Comment: it's still not a textarea but an editable div but i hope it fulfills your request :)

Comment: Okey... let's hope so :) :)

Comment: For everyone who ever make a website from scratch, that question may become really clear. Most problem related to it, is because we do not allow users to drag image directly to text area (in my case). The best solution, at least for me, is to use one of text editor like bootstrap or html5 that has image icon. Modify the popup  to load your images from gallery using Ajax.