# How to insert an image inside a <textarea> tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to create a blog. So I'm using textarea tag to insert text, but at the same time, in case, if I want to insert an image inside a textarea field how do i do that?

P.s: I have used 
input type="file"
to fetch the image from my system. Now I want this image to be inserted into the textarea field.

Comment: You can use CK editor (http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279671/how-to-pass-an-image-into-a-html-textarea

Comment: Take a look at tinymce: https://www.tinymce.com

Answer (score 0):

The textarea element is supposed to contain any text, with markup too, but no rich text formatting provided from the box. 
You have to integrate some javascript text editor to do that; there's lots of lightweight HTML5 editors that transform textareas into a rich text editors with image insert buttons.
Or, you may just insert an <img> tag into your text.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to not use a textarea at all and instead use:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then you can style it to look like a textarea

```
div[contenteditable] {
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid #555555;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   min-height: 50px;
}
```

Then you can put HTML in it.

However, the suggestions to use an actual html editor are probably the better way to go, rather than build your own.